# New-AzureADPolicy missed in the Azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

New-AzureADPolicy missed in the Azure cloud shell

```
New-AzureADPolicy : The term 'New-AzureADPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
    Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Also if try to install AzureADPreview

```
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview
```

The result is:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to load shared library 'api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libapi-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to work somehow with Azure AD in the web cloud shell?

Comment: It is not support to install module in cloud shell, you could just install it in local.

Comment: but maybe one month ago it was available command and I use claim mapping policy, also I have the same errors locally

Comment: You mean `Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview` works in cloud shell one month ago? AFAIK, the cloud shell never supports to install module.

Comment: I mean New-AzureADPolicy was available before

Comment: Also if Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview locally the same error on windows 10

Comment: what is your powershell version?

Comment: Locally 5.1.17134.858 Web 6.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AzureAD` Module is included in Azure cloud shell, but `New-AzureADPolicy` is **now only exist** in `AzureADPreview` Module and we can not install this Module in Azure cloud shell. So we can not run `New-AzureADPolicy` in Azure cloud shell.

But we can run most AzureAD command list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#policies) in Azure cloud shell, no need to install AzureAD module.